# Calculate spans opacity in a Vignette effect manner

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a flex container with seven date spans. I want the center date span (marked blue) to have an opacity of 1 and each subsequent span from center to have its opacity diminished.

[image]

I'm trying to come up with a simple algorithm to do this dynamically on a non fixed length of date span.

> i.e.
>   Opacity values
>
> 0.1, 0.3, 0.6, |1|, 0.6 0.3 0.1

To get this result:

[image]

Obviously in this example I have the length of date spans [7] and a value of each iteration [0, 1, 2 ...6]

Comment: Hi Johnny, please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your HTML structure as following, we have:

```js
const nav = document.getElementById('nav')
const maxOpacity = 1
const divs = nav.querySelectorAll('div')
const range = maxOpacity/divs.length*2

const opacities = Array(divs.length).fill(1)

for(var i=0; i<opacities.length;i++) { 
  let res = range*(i+1)

  if(res >= 1) {
    opacities[i] = 1
    break
  }
  opacities[i] = res
}

for(;i<opacities.length;i++) {
  opacities[i] = opacities[opacities.length - 1 - i]
}


nav.querySelectorAll('div').forEach((div, index) => {
  div.style.opacity = opacities[index]
})
```

```css
#nav {
background: green;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-around;
}

#nav div {
color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
  <div>Item 4</div>
  
  <div>Item 5</div>
  
  <div>Item 6</div>
  <div>Item 7</div>
  <div>Item 8</div>
  <div>Item 9</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little function that calculates the opacity using some *fancy* math:

```
function getOpacity(length, index) {
  return Math.sin((1 / (length - 1) * index) * Math.PI);
}
```

You just pass in the count of your `<span>`'s and the index of the current one.

#### Explanation

First, the function will calculate the position of the item on a "scale" from `0` to `1`. This will be `0` for the first, `.5` for the middle and `1` for the last one. Then, that value will be multiplied by π (`Math.PI`). The result of that will be passed to `Math.sin` creating an output like this:

[image: fancy math]

*https://ggbm.at/m6zRvScc*

Comment: I think, what you're missing is that index has nothing to do with the requirement. Nice suggestion otherwise!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Would calling the function multiple times and putting the values into an array complete the answer or what are you saying? He said he wanted "to come up with a simple algorithm" and I thought I provided him with one.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>After seeing those tiny arrows I suppose you want to dynamically set those opacity **while scrolling** the parent.</sup>
I'll show you **two ideas**, one that uses **CSS-only**, and one with **JavaScript** (jQuery)

## CSS-only way:

- Add a **gradient background  overlay** DIV with "click-trough" capability

[image]

```css
/*QuickReset*/* {margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;}html,body {height:100%;font:14px/1.4 sans-serif;}

.scrollWrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.scrollWrapper:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px; /* any height just to cover the .date text */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none; /* let click go-trough */
  /* http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#29dca4+0,000000+50,29dca4+100&1+0,0+50,1+100 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(41,220,164,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(41,220,164,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(41,220,164,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(41,220,164,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(41,220,164,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(41,220,164,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#29dca4', endColorstr='#29dca4',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
.scroll {
  background: #29DCA4;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.date {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 65px;
  margin: 0 15px;
  color: #fff;
}
.date:first-child { margin-left: 50%;}
.date:last-child { margin-right: 50%;}

.date b { color: #2D476A;}
```

```html
<div class="scrollWrapper">
  <div class="scroll">
    <span class="date"><b>10</b> 2/15/2018</span>
    <span class="date"><b>20</b> 2/15/2019</span>
    <span class="date"><b>30</b> 2/15/2020</span>
    <span class="date"><b>40</b> 2/15/2021</span>
    <span class="date"><b>50</b> 2/15/2022</span>
    <span class="date"><b>60</b> 2/15/2023</span>
    <span class="date"><b>70</b> 2/15/2024</span>
    <span class="date"><b>80</b> 2/15/2025</span>
    <span class="date"><b>90</b> 2/15/2026</span>
    <span class="date"><b>10</b> 2/15/2027</span>
    <span class="date"><b>20</b> 2/15/2028</span>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

## JavaScript way

- Get the scrollable parent width and get the center coordinate (`width / 2`)
- Get each `.date` and access `.css()` `"opacity"` property and return a value from `0` to `1` which is the result of the iterated child center distance from the parent center:

```js
var $date = $(".scroll .date");

function setDatesOpacity() {
  var center = $(this).width() / 2;         // Calculate parent center

  $date.css("opacity", function() {
    var bcr = this.getBoundingClientRect(); // Get this rect values
    var x = bcr.left + bcr.width / 2;       // Get this center x
    return Math.max(0, 1 + -Math.abs((x - center) / center)); // Return new opacity
  });
}

$(".scroll").on("scroll", setDatesOpacity); // Do on parent scroll
$(window).on("resize", setDatesOpacity);    // Do if window resizes
setDatesOpacity();                          // Do once when possible
```

```css
/*QuickReset*/
* {margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;}
html,body {height:100%;font:14px/1.4 sans-serif;}


.scroll {
  background: #29DCA4;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.date {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 65px;
  margin: 0 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

.date:first-child {
  margin-left: 50%;
}

.date:last-child {
  margin-right: 50%;
}

.date b {
  color: #2D476A;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  <span class="date"><b>10</b> 2/15/2018</span>
  <span class="date"><b>20</b> 2/15/2019</span>
  <span class="date"><b>30</b> 2/15/2020</span>
  <span class="date"><b>40</b> 2/15/2021</span>
  <span class="date"><b>50</b> 2/15/2022</span>
  <span class="date"><b>60</b> 2/15/2023</span>
  <span class="date"><b>70</b> 2/15/2024</span>
  <span class="date"><b>80</b> 2/15/2025</span>
  <span class="date"><b>90</b> 2/15/2026</span>
  <span class="date"><b>10</b> 2/15/2027</span>
  <span class="date"><b>20</b> 2/15/2028</span>
</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

The above is just a proof of concept, you should improve it by:

- limiting the number of `.date` elements (to just the visible ones)
- don't do heavy stuff on window resize but once it finishes resizing
- Make the above expandable to any number of `.scroll` elements (currently works only for one)